# Storing photos and videos privately with Google

Tags: google-drive, privacy, picasa-web-albums

I am interested in purchasing extra Google storage to use in storing mainly photos and videos.

Is it possible to keep everything I store private with Picasa or Google Docs?

Comment: You are aware that in many 'online storage' solutions T&C's that any uploaded content will become legally theirs? (not necessarily the one mentioned)

Comment: No actually I was not aware of this. Do you use any cloud solution to store photos and videos? What would you suggest? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! Both those sites are able to keep their contents private - you are in control of the security settings.

I would suggest picasa for photos and videos because it is aimed squarely at those formats.